# how to catch the power button on wince?

Tags: c++, windows-ce

I would like to catch the power button flagged as VK_TPOWER in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb431750.aspx) how is it possible ?

Comment: I hope none; when I want to turn off my phone, I wouldn't like any programm to interfer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [power manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms893838.aspx) is the only interface I can think of :

But I am not so sure that it will let you do anything you want with the power button, it is probably strictly limited in what you can do with it :

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ce_base/archive/2008/04/30/windows-ce-power-management.aspx)'s a link that could help

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C# have a look at the [OpenNetCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/). There is the OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.PowerManagement.PowerDown event that you can use.

I also recommend to read this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WiMoPower1.aspx) in order to understand how power management works.